# How to optimize slow queries with hundreds of values in NOT IN?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, percona

I have the two following two Wordpress queries that's really slow that I use Query Monitor plugin to identify.

There are only less than 2400 rows in `wp_posts` table.

The server has 2 cores and the load average is around 0.5

I'm using Percona Server where `mysql -V` gives me:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20-19, for Linux (x86_64) using  6.2
```

The `NOT IN` part is always the same, and there is about 400 items to exclude and could be up to 1000

Is there a way to optimize the query or to make use of `index` to speed up the performance?

Or is there a better approach to make post exclusion that is more efficient?

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, (t1.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_average, (t2.meta_value+0.00) AS ratings_users
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS t1
ON t1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
AND t1.meta_key = 'ratings_score'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta As t2
ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
AND t2.meta_key = 'ratings_users'
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890)
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY ratings_average desc, ratings_users desc
LIMIT 0, 12

SELECT p.ID AS id, p.post_title AS title, p.post_author AS uid, SUM(v.pageviews) AS pageviews
FROM `wp_popularpostssummary` v
LEFT JOIN `wp_posts` p
ON v.postid = p.ID
WHERE 1 = 1
AND p.post_type IN('post', 'page')
AND p.ID NOT IN(123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890)
AND v.view_datetime > DATE_SUB('2018-02-15 05:48:36', INTERVAL 29 DAY)
AND p.post_password = ''
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY v.postid
ORDER BY pageviews DESC
LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Have you tried putting those `not in` values in a table and using that instead? ...But I can't help but notice, this seems contradictory "The NOT IN part is always the same, and there is about 400 items to exclude and could be up to 1000"

Comment: I haven't implemented the `not in` values into a table, currently it's a string of values manually flagged that I have it hard coded into the php code that's initiating the queries.

Comment: Having an evolving list of ID values in any code is seldom a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the values in a table, and joining against it, or using it's values as a subquery for the NOT IN list.

```
...
FROM wp_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN wp_posts_flagged AS f ON p.ID = f.ID -- optionally: AND f.flag_type = X
...
WHERE f.ID IS NULL
...
```

or

```
WHERE p.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts_flagged)
```

Comment: Is the second method `WHERE p.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts_flagged)` essentially the same as my original query where the subquery return a list of posts to be used in `NOT IN`?  Is it going to increase the query performance?

Comment: While I cannot be positive, I am pretty sure the implementors of MySql would have some optimizations in place so this form of the NOT IN was better than its raw list form. (Even then, I would still go with the JOIN version I presented.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JOIN operation syntax.  I'll look into it and test the implementation.  What is the optional `f.flag_type = X` used for in your first method?

Comment: It's just based off a presumption I made that this is for some kind of blacklist functionality; if that was near correct flag_type would allow the one table to be used for multiple purpose "blacklisted" could be one flag type, another could be "flagged for review/moderator approval", etc...